# APEX Testing ErrorLoggingSystem__c.getInstance()

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have code that I need to cover:

```java
private static void log(String developerMessage, String exceptionMessage, String stackTrace, String exceptionType) {
    ErrorLoggingSettings__c els = ErrorLoggingSettings__c.getInstance();
    if (els.enabled__c) {
        Exception_Log__c log = new Exception_Log__c(
            DeveloperMessage__c = developerMessage,
            Message__c          = exceptionMessage,
            StackTrace__c       = stackTrace,
            Type__c             = exceptionType
        );        
        insert log;
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to set the current instance of ErrorLoggingSettings__c to enabled. I don't even understand what getInstance() is. Can someone explain to me please? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Formatting code as blocks involves making _every_ line indented at least 4 spaces (the "only add spaces to the first line" approach messes with indentation and leaves the final line unformatted). This can be done by highlighting your code and clicking the `{}` button. Alternatively, you can use 3 backticks on the line before your code starts and 3 backticks on the line after it ends (as I have done for you).

Comment: Thanks @Derek F, I thought I had done that but evidently not.

Comment: Also, I can gather that `ErrorLoggingSettings__c` is a custom setting, but is it a List Custom Setting or a Hierarchy Custom Setting? I'd wager that it's a Hierarchy Custom Setting. If so, you should read through the [documentation on Custom Settings' Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm)

Comment: How would I know if it is one or the other? I would guess you are correct, but even so after reading the documentation I don't understand how to cover this code in a test. I tried inserting ErrorLoggingSettings__c myels = new ErrorLoggingSettings__c(Name='Test Name', Enabled__c=TRUE); before calling the method but in the class els.enabled__c never returns true and the rest of the code is never covered.

Comment: Did you not add this custom setting yourself (did you "inherit" a mature org)? Go into the setup menu (in Salesforce), type "Custom Settings" in the quick find box, and then find your custom setting (by the "label" column) and look at the "Settings Type" column.

Comment: Yes it is a "mature" org I inherited. Yes it is Hierarchy. I added the following code to the class and it works. But is it the best idea?

        if(Test.isRunningTest()){
            ErrorLoggingSettings__c myels = new ErrorLoggingSettings__c(Name='Test Name', Enabled__c=TRUE);
            els = myels;
        }

Comment: Test.isRunningTest is almost never the right answer; mock the custom setting in the testmethod

Answer (score 2):

Custom Settings are data (not metadata), so they need to be created/inserted in a unit test just like all other data (excepting things like Users, Profiles, etc... collectively known as "Setup Objects").

```java
// This would be in your test methods
// ...or ideally in the @TestSetup method in your test class so you only have
//   to write this code once
ErrorLoggingSettings__c myels = new ErrorLoggingSettings__c(Name='Test Name', Enabled__c=TRUE);

// This is the part you missed, you need to insert the custom setting
insert myels;
```

Then, when the method you're testing calls `ErrorLoggingSettings__c.getInstance()`, it'll be able to return that data. Without doing the insert, you're at the mercy of the default behavior (which since API v21.0 has been to return an 'empty' instance of the custom setting).

#### Inserting test records for Custom Settings isn't the only way

DML in tests makes them run slow(er than they can otherwise execute in), and the org-wide nature of custom settings means that performing DML on them is problematic if you're running tests in parallel.

If your code is written with care and attention given to being able to test it, you can avoid the DML. Probably the most common way to achieve this is to use *Dependency Injection* (DI). In a nutshell, instead of creating the object instances, that a method needs to run, you pass them into the method (creating them elsewhere).

```java
// traditional, non-DI approach
public void playPoker(){
    CardDeck deck = new CardDeck();

    deck.deal();
}

// DI approach (specifically, parameter injection)
public void playPoker(CardDeck deck){
    deck.deal();
}
```

By not constructing the instance of a class you're using in the method it's being used in, you can create your own instance in your test class and simply pass it in.

In your particular case, a simple, test-friendly way to get this Custom Setting into your method without DML would be to make `els` a class-level static variable (instead of a local variable in the static method)

```java
public class YourClass{
    // Initializing els using getInstance() gives us a default value to work with.
    // This would only be a problem in tests and when running 'for real' if the
    //   API version is <= 21.0
    public static ErrorLoggingSettings__c els = ErrorLoggingSettings__c.getInstance();

    private static void log(String developerMessage, String exceptionMessage, String stackTrace, String exceptionType) {
        // This local variable is no longer required (or desired)
        //ErrorLoggingSettings__c els = ErrorLoggingSettings__c.getInstance();
        if (els.enabled__c) {
            Exception_Log__c log = new Exception_Log__c(
                DeveloperMessage__c = developerMessage,
                Message__c          = exceptionMessage,
                StackTrace__c       = stackTrace,
                Type__c             = exceptionType
            );        
            insert log;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your test method(s), you could override the default

```java
@isTest
static void callLog_normalPath_writesALog(){
    YourClass.els = new ErrorLoggingSettings__c(Enabled__c = true);

    Test.startTest();
    // Because log() no longer calls getInstance(), and we've explicitly overwritten
    //   the "els" variable, it no longer matters that the custom setting has
    //   not been inserted.
    // To the logic inside of log(), "els" is populated with data, and that's all
    //   it cares about.
    YourClass.log('one fish', 'two fish', 'red fish', 'blue fish');
    Test.stopTest();

    // some assertions here
}
```

You could also use [the Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) here because the custom settings methods are not static. I personally find that a bit cumbersome though.

Comment: Thanks! Liefsaver.